# Node object reference basics

Tags: nodes

I am very new to Drupal programming and I am now trying to take my first steps there. I want to start off with the very basics such as iterate thought the items of a node and print them.

Based on this [node object reference](http://drupal.org/node/49768) I have something like this in my code

```
$value = $node->title;
dpm($value , $name = "Node's title");
```

but how would I iterate though the node's fields. Here's an example of some fields printed from devel

> field_event (Array, 1 element)

```
0 (Array, 5 elements)
    value (String, 19 characters ) 2012-03-17 08:00:00
    value2 (String, 19 characters ) 2012-03-18 15:00:00
    timezone (String, 13 characters ) Europe/Athens
    timezone_db (String, 3 characters ) UTC
    date_type (String, 8 characters ) datetime
```

> field_city (Array, 1 element)

```
0 (Array, 2 elements)
    tid (String, 1 characters ) 1
    taxonomy_term (Object) stdClass
        tid (String, 1 characters ) 1
        vid (String, 1 characters ) 2
        name (String, 10 characters ) London
        description (String, 0 characters )
        format (String, 13 characters ) filtered_html
        weight (String, 1 characters ) 0
        vocabulary_machine_name (String, 4 characters ) city
        rdf_mapping (Array, 5 elements)
```

The first one is a date object and the second one is a taxonomy object. How would I access their data? Let's say I want the value2 for the date field and the name of the taxonomy term. Is this how you would go grab them?

```
$value = $node->field_event[0]->value2;
$value = $node->field_city[0]->taxonomy_term->name;
```

I am pretty confused on how you iterate though this maze of objects and arrays. Any simple explanations with examples?

Comment: It seems to me that you are exactly right with your syntax, so I don't understand where the trouble is.

Comment: The problem is that the statements I wrote don't work. So the syntax can't be right. Are you sure that this is the way to retrieve these values?

Comment: In what context do you use these statements ? To be sure about what's available, you can `dpm` what you want in a progressive way, first `$node`, then `$node->field_whatever`and so on. You'll see where the error is. I can assure you I use that kind of syntax successfully on a daily basis.

Comment: That is useful  If I try `dpm($node->field_event , $name = "Event");` I get as a result  `... (Array, 1 element)
    und (Array, 1 element)
        0 (Array, 5 elements)
            value (String, 19 characters ) 2012-04-26 09:00:00
            value2 (String, 19 characters ) 2012-04-28 09:00:00
            timezone (String, 13 characters ) Europe/Athens
            timezone_db (String, 3 characters ) UTC
            date_type (String, 8 characters ) datetime`  How do I keep going even further down? If I try `$node->field_event[0]` I get Undefined offset: 0. It is an array shouldn't it work?

Comment: I think i finally figured it out. This syntax seems to work `dpm($node->field_event['und'][0]['value'] , $name = "Event");`